# Setting up initial state of the reducer in react-redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

Hey guys I am stuck at a situation where i need to set the initial state of a reducer to some value .After reading docs i came to know we can also set the initial state like this one below

```
export default function(state = 0, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "credits":
        return action.payload
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

but my problem is little bit different
i have first reducer which is like this

authreducer.js

```
 export default function(state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "fetchuser":
          let data=action.payload||false;
          return {...state,fetchuser:data}
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

and another one like this

creditreducer.js

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "credits":
        return action.payload
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

In `creditreducer`, I want the default value of state to be the state value, which was returned by the `authreducer`.

```
  return {...state,fetchuser:data}
```

How can I set that value to be initial state for `creditreducer`? Somehow `creditreducer.js` needs to access the state in file `authrecuer.js` first. Then, it should set the state to a value returned by it for the initial value of the state from `creditreducer`.

Comment: In general, I think redux's design patterns attempt to make reducers completely independent from each other as it doesn't follow the design patterns well -> so I would avoid it for the shear fact it's anti-pattern. However, if it's unavoidable, checkout [this link](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/749#issue-107159303) where its discussed what the best way is of going about doing this. It still may not answer your question regarding multiple files though. However, you can handle that with import/exports with NodeJS.

Comment: you should change logic to solve your problem because setting one reducer's returned value as initial state for another it is completely wrong!